# How to start a process from a WCFservice

Tags: wcf

I have a window service service1. service1 is running a process.I have called this window service inside a webservice. But it will not allow to start the process while calling the service1 from webservice.
Please find the code below.

**Service1**

```
namespace ContinuousIntegration
 {
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContIntegService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Execute(string Component);
}

// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
// You can add XSD files into the project. After building the project, you can directly use the data types defined there, with the namespace "ContinuousIntegration.ContractType".
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ContIntegService : IContIntegService
{
       public string Execute(string component)
       {
        if(component == "Verification")
        {
             string exeFileName = string.Empty;
             string workingDirectory = string.Empty;
             string ServerArguments = string.Empty;
             string moderatorPath = string.Empty;
             string output = string.Empty;
             workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(moderatorPath); ;
        exeFileName = Path.GetFileName(moderatorPath);
        ServerArguments = string.Concat("-c", " ", "TC", " ", "-r", " ", reportpath);
        P = new Process();
        try
        {
            if (P != null)
            {
                P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                P.StartInfo.WindowStyle =   System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                P.StartInfo.FileName = exeFileName;
                P.StartInfo.Arguments = ServerArguments;
                P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                runStatus = P.Start();
                P.WaitForExit(5000);
                while (!File.Exists(reportpath + "\\" + "TestCaseAll.html"))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                output = "Completed";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
            runStatus = false;
        }
        runStatus = true;
        return output;

       }
     }
   }
```

**WebService**

```
public string ExecuteWindowService(string component)
    {            
        string result = string.Empty;
        ServiceReference1.ContIntegServiceClient myService = new ServiceReference1.ContIntegServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IContIntegService");
        myService.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        myService.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        myService.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        myService.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        result = myService.Execute(component);
        myService.Close();           
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: if you hit your service in postman is it working?

Comment: What does it say to you? What is inside 'msg' after you try to start the process?

Comment: Exception is Access denied.